# Update database using Jquery Ajax Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, database

I have a list item with a name I would like to edit. When my .editActivity button is clicked, I use Jquery to change the name of the list item which works great. I would like to use Jquery's Ajax to update the name in my database. I feel like the problem is happening in my activities_controller.rb or routes.rb but not sure.

```
  <ul class="list-group-sortable" id="Activities" >
<h1 align = "center">Activities</h1>

  <!-- List each activity in database -->
  <%  @activities.each do |activity| %>
    <li class="list-group-item" id="item" style="list-style: none;">

      <label class="my_label"><%= activity.a_name %></label>

      <!-- Edit activity -->
     <!-- link_to 'edit activity', edit_activity_path(activity) do %>-->
          <button class="editActivity" style="border:none; padding:0; background-color: transparent">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" title="Edit" id="editActivity"></i>
          </button>
     <!-- end %>-->

    </li> <!-- End of list item -->
    <% end %> <!-- End of if statement -->
  <% end %> <!-- End of activity loop -->
```

This is my Jquery for changing the name and ajax:

```
  //Edit Activity
$('#Activities li .editActivity').click(function() {
    var name = $(this).closest('li').text();
    $('span').text("text is: " + name);
    var input = $('<input id="attribute" class="textbox" type="text" value="' + name + '" />')
    $(this).closest('li').append(input); 
    input.select(); 
    input.blur(function(event) {
        var text = $('input:text').val();
        $(event.target).closest('li').find('label').text(text);
        $('#attribute').remove(); //removes the newly created text box

            //ajax request to update database
        $(document).ajaxError(function(){
            alert("Error with AJAX call!");
            alert($(this).closest('li').attr('id'));
        });

        $.ajax({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: '/activities/' + id,
            data: { a_name: text}
        });

    });
});
```

This is my update action in my activities_controller:

```
 def update
@activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
@activity.update_attributes(:a_name)
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {}
end
```

end

This is in my routes.rb:

```
put '/activities/:id' => 'activities#update'
```

Comment: `update.js.erb` file contains the javascript content that will be rendered after a successful `ajax` call (it is like `update.html.erb` but for javascript). The content depends on what you want to do after your `ajax` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the `headers` attribute in the `ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  },
  method: 'PUT',
  url: '/activities/' + id,
  data: { a_name: text }
});
```

And you also need to create an `update.js.erb` file for your `update` action to render.

**UPDATE**

I would also suggest to update your database first and then (if update is successful) change the name of the item on the page, just add `success` attribute to the `ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  },
  method: 'PUT',
  url: '/activities/' + id,
  data: { a_name: text },
  success: function(response) {
    // update item name here
  }
});
```

`response` contains whatever you put on your `update.js.erb` file.